# Is it possible to share data with threads without any cloning?

Tags: multithreading, rust, borrow-checker

When I'm delegating work to threads I often have a piece of data that will outlive all of the threads, such as `numbers` in the following example:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let thread_a = thread::spawn(|| println!("{}", numbers.len()));
    let thread_b = thread::spawn(|| println!("{}", numbers.len()));

    thread_a.join().unwrap();
    thread_b.join().unwrap();
}
```

It's not modified anywhere, and because of the `join`s, it's guaranteed that the threads are done using it. However, Rust's borrow checker is not able to tell:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `numbers`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/main.rs:6:34
  |
6 |     let thread_a = thread::spawn(|| println!("{}", numbers.len()));
  |                                  ^^                ------- `numbers` is borrowed here
  |                                  |
  |                                  may outlive borrowed value `numbers`
  |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 |     let thread_a = thread::spawn(|| println!("{}", numbers.len()));
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `numbers` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
6 |     let thread_a = thread::spawn(move || println!("{}", numbers.len()));
  |                                  ^^^^^^^
```

The solutions I've seen so far all involve cloning the piece of data (or cloning an `Arc` of the data). Is it possible to do it without any cloning, though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have the wrong idea: cloning an `Arc` is just incrementing a reference counter and making a copy of a pointer; it doesn't perform any additional allocation. Of course, creating the `Arc` involves an allocation, but then, you're already allocating in order to construct the `Vec`, so one additional fixed-size allocation isn't likely to hurt.

If all you *really* need is the length, you can just compute that *outside* the thread's closure and store it in a variable; a `usize` has no problems crossing a thread boundary.

The issue is that the compiler is unable to infer from the use of `join()` that a given thread is bound to a limited lifetime... it doesn't even try.

Before Rust 1.0, there *was* a `thread::scoped` constructor that allowed you to pass in non-`'static` references, but that had to be de-stabilised due to a memory safety issue.  See [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423) for alternatives.

Comment: Well, to put something in `Arc` you *do* perform an allocation.